# How can I apply 2 variables to a BeforePrint?

Tags: vba, excel

How, In VBA, can I apply both a Minimum Value to a cell before Print and a check that 2 cell values match? I have tried my self below and the Minimum value works bu the Cell compare does not?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    If Sheets("PURCHASE_RECEIPT").Range("G31").Value < "0.01" Then
        [g32] = IIf([g27] = [g31], "Yes", "No")
    If ([g32] = "No") Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Please fill in payment method fields before printing and check that the totals match")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Close both `If....logic` Use `End If` before starting another `If..`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you're getting a compilation/syntax error, you should be including it in your question.

Comment: Hi @Mat'sMug, thanks for having a look at this!
I am not getting any syntax errors, thats kind of why I hit a wall. The full story is...
I have an excel form that is a receipt that is filled in with 2 different auto totals, I need it to ensure the first "total" cell is > 0.01 and then to compare that cell to the other "total" and check they match before printing. However thinking on, as they are auto totals, it only needs to make sure the totals match before it allows a print out, however that is still the bit i cant get to work? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

With Sheets("PURCHASE_RECEIPT")
    If .Range("G31").Value < 0.01 Or .Range("G27").Value <> .Range("G31").Value Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Please fill in payment method fields before printing and check that the totals match")
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Perfect, Thanks so much. I had to put "End Sub" at the very bottom but it does exactly what I need!